# Python: Quick Sort

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

How to improve this code? In C++ we use templates to write function for all data types. How to write such code in python?

```
def get_input(): #to get input from user
    input_str = input("Enter elements to be sorted: ")
    try:
        lst = list(map(int, input_str.split())) #make a list of integers from input string
    except:
        raise TypeError("Please enter a list of integers only, seperated by a space!!")
    return lst

def partition(thelist, start_idx, end_idx): #partition list according to pivot and return index of pivot
    pivot = thelist[end_idx] #select last element as the pivot
    idx = start_idx - 1

    for curr_idx in range(start_idx, end_idx):
        if thelist[curr_idx] <= pivot:
            idx += 1
            thelist[idx], thelist[curr_idx] = thelist[curr_idx], thelist[idx] #swapping

    thelist[idx+1], thelist[end_idx] = thelist[end_idx], thelist[idx+1] #swapping
    return idx+1 #returning pivot index

def quick_sort(thelist, start_idx, end_idx):
    if len(thelist) == 0:
        print("Empty list!!")

    elif len(thelist) == 1:
        print("Only one element!!")

    elif start_idx < end_idx:
        pivot_idx = partition(thelist, start_idx, end_idx) #get pivot index
        quick_sort(thelist, start_idx, pivot_idx - 1) #apply algorithm for smaller list
        quick_sort(thelist, pivot_idx + 1, end_idx) #apply algorithm for smaller list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_list = get_input()
    quick_sort(input_list, 0, len(input_list) - 1)
    print(*input_list, sep = ", ")
```

Comment: Why would you want to have typed versions of your sorting algorithm in the first place?

Comment: I am learning python and I think this is best to practice algorithms and to learn new language.

Comment: I don't know that much, I thought writing such programs will help me to learn python syntax and other functions available in Python. Should I not learn by writing such(Algorithms and Data Structures) programs?

Comment: @coder you can try PE or CodeAbbey or other sites to improve your skills. But it seems you are already good at it

Comment: What @Linny said. Also, I know it's a technicality, but a list with one or no elements is still technically sorted.

Comment: Note that your `partition()` picks the pivot.

Answer (score 2):

## Docstrings

You should include a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) at the beginning of every function, class, and module you write. This will allow documentation to determine what your code is supposed to do.7

## Variable Naming

Here is a list of variables/parameters that I would change. This increases readability, and makes the variables easier to understand.

```
input_str -> elements
thelist -> the_list
start_idx -> start_index
end_idx -> end_index
idx -> index
curr_idx -> current_index
```

A quick sentence about `thelist`. You have been pretty consistent throughout your program, but remember *all* variables and parameter names are `snake_case`.

## Constants Naming

All constants in your program should be UPPER_CASE.

## Operator Spacing

In python, and many other languages, we like to have our operators spaced out cleanly. They make the code easier to read and easier to comprehend. So when I see something like `1+1`, that's an instance red flag. You should separate this by having a space on either side of the operator, like `1 + 1`.

## `len(...) == 0` vs `not ...`

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.
>
> ```
> Yes: if not seq:
>      if seq:
>
> No:  if len(seq):
>      if not len(seq):
> ```

## print() vs quit()

You have a structure like so:

```
if len(thelist) == 0:
    print("Empty list!!")

elif len(thelist) == 1:
    print("Only one element!!")

elif start_idx < end_idx:
    ... run quick sort program ...
```

Instead of restricting running the quick sort program to an `elif`, the first two checks should be separate `if`s. Then, instead of using print(), use [quit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#quit). This will allow you to safely stop a program with a provided error message. Now, you can have the quick sort code run if the first two checks are false, like so:

```
if not the_list:
    quit("Empty List!")

if len(the_list) == 1:
    quit("Only one element!")

if start_idx < end_idx:
    ... run quick sort program ...
```

## Parameter spacing

There should *not* be spaces separating an operator and a parameter name / value. Change this:

```
print(*input_list, sep = ", ")
```

to this:

```
print(*input_list, sep=", ")
```